# Python calling shell script - no directory?

Tags: python, bash, find, subprocess

In a python script I call a bash script as follows:

```
subprocess.Popen(["./scan.sh", dir])
```

Inside that script, there is,

```
find $1 -name "*013*.txt" > found_files.txt
```

For some reason, the dir argument from python is translated into a version with quotes inside the bash script. Printing 'dir' in python yields the exact path as the user typed it:

```
~/Desktop/Files
```

however, find fails with

```
find: '~/Desktop/Files' no such directory
```

Running scan.sh manually with ~/Desktop/Files as the argument works fine. How come quotes are being put around it...?

Comment: “Running scan.sh manually with ~/Desktop/Files” Right after Files, press Tab (once or twice). The shell expands '~' for you, just like it expands it (without displaying it) before calling `scan.sh`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There aren't. What's happening is that the `~` is not being interpreted, as it's the shell's job to do so. Use [`os.path.expanduser()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) to expand the path before passing it to `subprocess`.

Answer (score 0):

use $HOME. the '~' is not expanding in quotes nor in double quotes.

```
python -c "import subprocess;subprocess.Popen(['./scan.sh', '~'])"
python -c "import subprocess;subprocess.Popen(['./scan.sh', '$HOME'])"
```

my scan.sh contain:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo =$1=
```

The first one print `=~=`, the second `=/Users/jomo=`.

Comment: Using `$HOME` won't help, since it is *also* the shell's job to expand environment variables.

Comment: but $HOME got expanded in double quotes. (not in single)

Comment: Consider everything passed to the command via `subprocess` as being surrounded in single quotes.

Comment: Wait so you're saying every argument passed in subprocess will be interpreted as if you literally typed it with singled quotes?